# Vectorize matrix operation with internal loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Can I vectorize : A.row.T * B.rows and then sum vertically for every A.row

```
 for i,row in enumerate(A2D) :
    a = np.sum(row.T * B2D, axis=0)
    C2D[i,:] = a
```

---

this seem to work, thanks

```
 np.einsum('ij,kj->ji', A2D,B2D).T
```

now i have to figure how it works ;0

```
In [84]: %timeit (b[None] * z[:,None]).sum(0)
3.59 µs ± 161 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [85]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,kj->ij', b,z)
2.62 µs ± 179 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: `row` looks like a 1d array. Transposition will not work on it. Are you sure your calculation is OK?

Comment: it is hard to describe with words... the code is what i want to vectorize

Comment: Is this the result you want? `(A2D[None] * B2D[:, None]).sum(0).T` or `np.einsum('ij,kj->ji', A2D, B2D)`

Comment: the result have to be 2D array

Comment: If you don't want to transpose, you can change `->ji` to `->ij` or use `(A2D[None] * B2D[:, None]).sum(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

Working from the `einsum`, lets make a pair of 2d arrays, with different 1st dim, but matching 2nd (the `3`):

```
In [31]: A2D =  np.arange(6).reshape(2,3); B2D = np.arange(4*3).reshape(4,3)
```

The `einsum` result:

```
In [33]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ij',A2D,B2D)
Out[33]: 
array([[  0,  22,  52],
       [ 54,  88, 130]])
```

Test the loop:

```
In [34]: C2D = np.zeros((2,3),int)
In [35]: for i,row in enumerate(A2D) :
    ...:     a = np.sum(row.T * B2D, axis=0)
    ...:     C2D[i,:] = a
    ...: 
In [36]: C2D
Out[36]: 
array([[  0,  22,  52],
       [ 54,  88, 130]])
```

It matches, but it's more complicated.

From the `einsum` I see that only the `k` dimension is summed.  That means we can also do:

```
In [38]: A2D*(B2D.sum(axis=0,keepdims=True))
Out[38]: 
array([[  0,  22,  52],
       [ 54,  88, 130]])
```

That is, reduce `B2D` to (3,), or with `keepdims`, a (1,3).  That broadcasts with the (2,3).

In your sum, `row` doesn't need `T`, since its 1d.  This may be clearer:

```
In [41]: for i in range(A2D.shape[0]):
...:     C2D[i,:]  = np.sum(A2D[i,:] * B2D, axis=0)
```

Another way to do your iteration - without the loop is to broadcast the arrays:

```
In [43]: A2D[:,None,:] * B2D[None,:,:]
Out[43]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  4],
        [ 0,  4, 10],
        [ 0,  7, 16],
        [ 0, 10, 22]],

       [[ 0,  4, 10],
        [ 9, 16, 25],
        [18, 28, 40],
        [27, 40, 55]]])
In [44]: (A2D[:,None,:] * B2D[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[44]: 
array([[  0,  22,  52],
       [ 54,  88, 130]])
```

Your `row*B2D` produces a 2d array, (3,)*(4,3)->(4,3), which is reduced to (3,) with the sum:

```
In [45]: A2D[0,:]*B2D
Out[45]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4],
       [ 0,  4, 10],
       [ 0,  7, 16],
       [ 0, 10, 22]])
In [46]: (A2D[0,:]*B2D).sum(0)
Out[46]: array([ 0, 22, 52])
```

The `einsum` version just makes it clearer that we can go ahead and sum the rows of `B2D` first:

```
In [47]: B2D.sum(0)
Out[47]: array([18, 22, 26])
```

Actually we don't need the `keepdims`, the (3,) broadcasts with (2,3) just fine:

```
In [48]: A2D*B2D.sum(0)
Out[48]: 
array([[  0,  22,  52],
       [ 54,  88, 130]])
```